# Shell Script to copy the file to another folder

Tags: shell-script, filenames

I have to write .sh file which will be called from .Net Application.

Script.sh has to move the file from rootdirectory to a specified folder.

I am expecting to pass SourceFilePath and DestinationFilePath as parameters for .sh file.

How to write a .sh file with parameters.

```
#vim script.sh
echo "\home\testuser\file.csv"
read a
echo "\home\admin\user2\data\file.csv"
read b
echo "Data will be moving from $a to $b"
mv $a  $b
echo "Moving done"

:wq

#chmod u+x script.sh
#./script.sh
```

Comment: Unix uses `/` as the directory separator in pathnames, not `\ `

Comment: Why backslashes if this is on linux, or are those not directory separators?

Comment: .Net and the Cygwin shell are not usable together.  You must either login to Cygwin and use `cp -i /path/to/sourcefile /path/to/copiedfile` or use `System.File.Copy` to copy the File outside of Cygwin.  This method is not advised as the encoding will be different.  The fact that this is an SMB Share is moot.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Data will be moving from $1 to $2."
mv -- "$1" "$2"
```

Save the script as `foo.sh`, make it executable (`chmod 744 foo.sh`) and run it giving the source and destination as arguments:

```
./foo.sh /home/testuser/file.csv /home/admin/user2/data/file.csv
```

I have no idea if this plays well with .Net but it will work as expected on a *nix platform.

Comment: See my comment above... He's trying to "cheat environments"  .NET will not copy/move from a virtualized environment cleanly as he will have encoding Issues, UTF-8 TO ASCII etc.

Comment: @ECarterYoung I have less than no knowledge of .Net. I had ignored that part until seeing your comment at which point I added the disclaimer at the end of my answer. This answers the only part of the Q that is vaguely on topic though so...

Comment: I agree about the Q/A but by answering we opened the proverbial "can of worms."

Comment: @ECarterYoung indeed. I'm expecting this to be closed soon.

Comment: @ECarterYoung , there is something called respect. I am not here to cheat any Environment. I have mentioned very clearly, i am new to Linux. I might be wrong or i might be right. Let me give a try. Thanks for downvoting, That doesn't stop my effort

Comment: @just Then I apologize, I should have worded it differently.  See [Here](http://superuser.com/questions/550317/is-there-a-command-line-tool-in-cygwin-to-copy-a-file-to-the-clipboard) in order to move the file to the clipboard.  Either way, there is no "bridge" to do what you ask directly.

Comment: http://www.example-code.com/vbdotnet/ssh_exec.asp   , I came across the sample code. I am able to do.